# PHP merge arrays from old to new configuration file

Tags: php, arrays, file, merge

My old configuration file for my application looks like:

```
<?php
return array(
    'URL' => 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace('public', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])),
    'DOMAIN' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    'PATH_CONTROLLER' => realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../') . '/application/controller/',
    'DEBUG' => true,
    'EMAIL_USED_MAILER' => 'phpmailer',
    'SEND_MAIL_TO' => 'myreal@email.com'
  );
```

New configuration file looks like:

```
<?php
return array(
    'URL' => 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace('public', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])),
    'DOMAIN' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    'PATH_CONTROLLER' => realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../') . '/application/controller/',
    'DEBUG' => false,
    'EMAIL_USED_MAILER' => 'phpmailer',
    'SEND_MAIL_TO' => 'your_mail@example.net',
    'SEND_MAIL_FROM' => '',
    'NEW_VAR' => 'foo'
  );
```

Now I want to merge these two files when run upgrade.php into new file which should look like:

```
<?php
return array(
    'URL' => 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace('public', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])),
    'DOMAIN' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    'PATH_CONTROLLER' => realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../') . '/application/controller/',
    'DEBUG' => true,
    'EMAIL_USED_MAILER' => 'phpmailer',
    'SEND_MAIL_TO' => 'myreal@email.com',
    'SEND_MAIL_FROM' => '',
    'NEW_VAR' => 'foo'
  );
```

I try with array_merge, but it doesn't work in my case because of variables like $_SERVER. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: What it sounds like you need is to write a script which parses the two config files and finds differences, then generates a new one. Depending upon the contents of the files you maybe able to use a simple bash command.

Comment: @varlogtim yes exactly, I was thinking about awk and sed too but prefer php solution...

Comment: What else is in the file? A possible start is reading the entire file into a variable, `explode` on `,`, then `explode` on `=>` which should give you an array of `key values` which you could then use to compare the keys to see if one exists which isn't in the other. However, it might be better just to string replace any fields that you want to keep. For example, the "myreal@email.com" with whatever you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

First, to verify I understood your question correctly - my answer is based on the following assumptions:

1. You are developing a PHP-application that is installed on multiple servers (either by yourself, or others can download your application).
2. Each installation can has it's own custom config, lets say in a file named `config.php`
3. You are reading this users configuration somewhere within your application, lets say you have a function for it like `getConfig() { $config = include('config.php'); return $config; }`
4. You are updating this application, and with that update comes some new configuration-options that the user can change.

If above are all true, then I suggest the following workflow:

1. DON'T touch the users-config file. Yes it can be done automatically, but it is quite hard to do this right, and the chance to mess things up is great. For example: What if a user has an option written over two lines - PHP-synctactically correct, but if you made the assumption in your upgrade.php that each config is on one line you would likely break his or hers config file.
2. Document the new configuration-options somewhere and/or provide a `config.example.php` with all available options.
3. Change the current existing `getConfig()`-function (from assumption 3) to something like below, so you do a safe merge that is guaranteed to work:

Code:

```
function getConfig() { 
    $applicationDefaultConfig = array(
        'SEND_MAIL_FROM' => '',
        'NEW_VAR' => 'foo'            
    );
    $usersConfig = include('config.php'); 
    return array_merge($applicationDefaultConfig, $usersConfig); 
}
```